# Split RSA private key into two parts securely

Tags: key-management, rsa

Let's say I have a RSA key pair: N, E, D, in which N, E are the public part, D is the private part.

I'd like to split the private part into two pieces, D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub>, and store them in two different places. Is it secure if I just choose D<sub>1</sub> as a random string (same length as D) and D<sub>2</sub> is calculated as D XOR D<sub>1</sub>?

Answer (score 7):

> I'd like to split the private part into two pieces, D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub>, and store them in two different places. Is it secure if I just choose D<sub>1</sub> as a random string (same length as D) and D<sub>2</sub> is calculated as D XOR D<sub>1</sub>?

Yes. This is known as the [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad), and it is the recommended approach. The only way to get the original secret will be to obtain *both* D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub>.

Make sure you use a Cryptographically Secure Random Number Generator such as `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: You can use urandom as well. See http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

Comment: You're right! If we think of D1 as the encryption key and D2 as the cipher text, it should not be possible to retrieve the plaintext without either of them.

Answer (score -3):

The rule is :

> Don't roll your own crypto

Also, you did not define what is "secure" to you? What are the threats etc.
Normally a key is encrypted on your disk (embedded in a certificate, or put in a keystore), so that you cannot access it without a passphrase. Doing what you do does not add any layer of security, as XOR is not a reliable way to encrypt information to maintain confidentiality.

Comment: What I meant by "secure" here is whether it is possible to figure out the private key if one of the pieces is compromised. Of course, different mechanisms can be applied to protect the keys on disk, but I am not discussing about them here.

Comment: The OP is suggesting a [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) against random data. This XOR OTP is more 'secure' than traditional encryption, assuming he uses a Cryptographically Secure Random Number Generator.

Comment: The problem with one-time pad is that it just shifts the key problem onto the pad itself.

Comment: @ThanhBui in that regard, yes you cannot derive the key from the random string D1, or the D part of the key. But it's the same if you just truncate the key in two part without using any XOR.

Comment: My key is '123456790' I separate it into '12345' and '67890', having access to '12345' does not tell you anything about the rest of the key.

Comment: Not really, that'd reduce half the security level of the key because now I only need to brute-force half of the key.

Comment: yes of course, this is just an example to say it does not add security. Having to brute force the key, or the one-time pad, is the same difficulty. If you get D2 you have to brute force D1 and vice-versa. Then you can still brute force D on it's own.

Comment: @M'vy The point with the proposed scheme is that you do not store `D`. You store `D1` and `D2` in different locations. For an attacker to gain access to my key, she needs to both break into my bank vault to get `D1` and search through my grand mothers cookie jar to get `D2`. Brute forcing is not interesting here, because we assume that the key is strong enough not to be brute forced. (An assumption that does not imply that *half the key* is strong enough not to be brute forced.)

Comment: The point is not to make it harder to brute force. It is to make it harder to steal the key, because you need to pull off two heists instead of one.

Comment: Ok, I see the idea a bit better. Though saying it's harder to steal is a bit of a leap, since we don't know anything about the context. If one place cannot be 'robbed', you'll better to store you key there in the first place. If it's just a manner of virtually increasing the time needed to steal it, it could be argued that this is better. Though, one might just steal your credentials. Depending on who stores the keys, it could be argued that pulling one heist or two is just the same. To conclude, the usefulness of this technique seems difficult to prove.

Comment: *"it could be argued that pulling one heist or two is just the same"* This is not true in all contexts.

Comment: If both servers are vulnerable to the same attack, it's trivial to repeat it.